# Custom language plugin - braces alignment when returning an object

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, psi, intellij-platform-psi

I am developing a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA which supports my custom Lua-based language formatting.

I expect to get following result

```
func () {
    //do something
    return {
        data = {
            v1 = "some value",
            v2 = 123
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting this:

```
func () {
    //do something
    return {
            data = {
                       v1 = "some value",
                       v2 = 123
                   }
            }
}
```

The issue is that the closing braces after return statement are getting aligned with the opening.
To align braces in a Java style I tried most obvious combinations of indents and wrappings but with no luck.

I have not implemented any Code Style Settings for my language but when debugging I see that CommonSettings contains HTML, XML, JAVA and JSON CommonCodeStyleSettings.
Cleaning up myCommonSettingsMap and myCustomSettingsMap in bebugger did not remedy the situation.

I assume some default settings are involved but I have no idea what to check. Could somebody help me?

Comment: I'd recommend you raise this issue at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development to discuss it with the IDEA team directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer at IntelliJ forum: [How to make the Indent relative to direct parent's parents?](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5052654755602-How-to-make-the-Indent-relative-to-direct-parent-s-parents-)

In my code I always used a default Alignment:

```
Block block = new Simplek(child, Wrap.createWrap(WrapType.NONE, false), 
                  Alignment.createAlignment(), spacingBuilder);
```

The solution is to pass null when alignment is not needed.